# Audible does not download audiobook on mobile data

Tags: mobile-data, downloading, audible

I'm using Audible for Android, and when I purchased a book, I'm not able to download it over mobile data.

I have ensured that background data is enabled both system-wide and for Audible, but Audible still would not download. After I tap *Continue* on the "Data Usage Notice", Audible only shows the following on the book:

- Waiting to download...
- Retrying 2 of 5
- Retrying 3 of 5
- Retrying 4 of 5
- Retrying 5 of 5
- Retrying 6 of 5 *(huh?)*
- **Invalid data format**

Is there anything else I should do to have it download the audiobook over mobile data? Or is it possible to do it over WiFi only? (I can download over WiFi without any problem.)

It is possible that my mobile network service provider actively blocks Audible downloads, however, there were no reports about this that I could find online.

My device is OnePlus 2 running stock Android Marshmallow.

Comment: Can you [try changing the format](http://audible.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5128/kw/Invalid%20data%20format) for the *same* audiobook and see ?

Comment: @beeshyams those instructions seem outdated. I don't find any such drop-down in the Library page. I also suspect that it's not really a format problem, but the app is *incorrectly* handling the condition of not being able to download.

Comment: @beeshyams I spoke too soon. Saw the option after I "expand" the book details and click "Download options". I will try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a mobile data issue, since

1. You have not reported any problems with any other downloads on data
2. It is more likely a *format* issue (error says **Invalid Data Format**) and Audible website says **Not all portable devices support all formats**. Details below

[What is an Audible format, and how do I choose the one that best suits me?](http://audible.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5128/kw/Invalid%20data%20format) says

> Audible offers **four** different types of audio formats to choose from, depending upon the device you wish to use to listen to your audiobooks. The audio format is determined by the rate of compression.
>
> Note: Not all portable devices support all formats.

These formats correspond to quality as in *AM, FM, MP3, CD*

To change these formats one would need to log in [desktop site](http://www.audible.com/) per instructions on the linked page (in essence, *Library →Audio quality drop down menu*)

Comment: Your answer would only make sense if the Audible app is designed to download two different formats depending on whether I choose to download the book over mobile data or WiFi. Funny thing, it might just be designed that way (and I have no control over it, except *maybe, just maybe,* inconveniently through desktop site to be set per **each book**). Because when I had started the download over WiFi and later switched to mobile data, the download *continued* without any problem. This needs further investigation. I'll vote you up in any case.

Comment: I see your point, but it is perhaps best to write to the developer explaining your situation ,  and seeking clarity on *Not all portable devices support all formats*

Comment: Meanwhile, it wouldn't hurt to see if changing the format for downloading on mobile makes a difference, your experiment of starting out on WiFi  and switching to mobile notwithstanding

Comment: No, I tried all the four formats through the desktop site, but the mobile app still would not download on mobile data. **Once I connect to WiFi it downloads without any problem.** I don't this there is an *actual* data format issue here. It's a modern smartphone, not some odd MP3 player. And the issue is isolated to one of the two channels of data transfer only. I think this is a bug in the app.

Comment: Surprising and best course would be to raise a bug report. All the best and do update your findings to help others in future. Thanks